# Impossible to style the form submit button

Tags: html, css, forms

Edit: Solved, see comments!

I've read a few posts about styling submit buttons in forms, but it only seems to partially work with me. I'm able to change the border, but not the background color or font settings. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code? I'm new to forms, so I could have just n00bed. I've tried background, background-color, hexadecimal values... I just am stumped.

```
#submitButton {
color: black;
background: #cac9c9;
border: 4px solid blue;
```

}

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="user@domain.com" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <hr />
    <div id="checkboxContainer">
        <span>Select the newsletters you'd like to receive</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="travel" value="Getaways" />
        <label>Destinations &#38; Getaways</label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="travel" value="Tips" />
        <label>Weekly Travel Tips</label>
    </div>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="SIGN UP" />
</form>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4J2S4/1/ Looks fine to me

Comment: what web-browser are you testing in ?  IE6 ?

Comment: Use a debugging tool like firebug to inspect the element in question. It will tell you where the styling elements come from, and will help you find the error.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome. While I have my debugger running the whole time, I took another look at it and actually figured it out! I had another input selector in the css that was affecting this one as well (in short, a background image was covering things up in this input). Thanks for the quick responses!!

Comment: I suggest you take a look at `!important` property

Answer (score 1):

[Click for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vq2D9/)

### Css

```
.classname {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #63b8ee), color-stop(1, #468ccf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#63b8ee', endColorstr='#468ccf');
    background-color:#63b8ee;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:20px;
    border-top-left-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:20px;
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #3866a3;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#14396a;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    width:86px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #7cacde;
}
.classname:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #468ccf), color-stop(1, #63b8ee) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#468ccf', endColorstr='#63b8ee');
    background-color:#468ccf;
}.classname:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

[I forked your jsfiddle example and solution is here it works](http://jsfiddle.net/JNe2s/1/)

Comment: You can write all the `border-radius` crap in one line like `border-radius: 20px;` that's it

Comment: Can't tell if trolling with vendor prefixes or very ignorant…

Comment: I solved it! I had another input selector in the css affecting this one as well! Thanks though!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-top-left-radius.asp check it out it doesnt matter if its vendor prefix or any other crap was only trying to help